# Existence of an algebraic integer satisfying a particular condition

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraic extension of the rationals of degree $n$ and let $\{ 1, \omega_2, \omega_3, \dots , \omega_n \}$ be an integral basis for the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ of $K$. Let $\alpha \in \mathcal{O}_K$ be primitive, meaning no rational prime divides $\alpha$, and assume that the ideal $(\alpha )$ is prime to the discriminat of $K$. Does there exist an integer $\beta \in \mathcal{O}_K$ such that $\alpha \beta = 1 + c_2 \omega_2 + c_3 \omega_3 + \dots + c_n \omega_n$ , where the $c_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

The question has been modified after Professor Lozano-Robledo's excellent answer. I added the condition that $(\alpha )$ is prime to the discriminat of $K$.

Comment: Where $c_2,\ldots,c_n$ are arbitrary coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, I assume?

Comment: Thanks Alex! I edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, in general. Here is a counterexample.

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$. The ring of integers is $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ (for this see for instance these [notes by Keith Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/Qw2.pdf)). Let $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2}$. Then $\alpha$ is "primitive" (the norm of $\alpha$ is $2$, and $2=\alpha^3$, so no rational prime divides $\alpha$). Now let $\beta\in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ be arbitrary, i.e., $\beta=a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\sqrt[3]{4}$. Then:
$$\alpha\cdot \beta = 2c+a\sqrt[3]{2}+b\sqrt[3]{4}.$$
Therefore, $\alpha\cdot\beta$ is never equal to a number of the form $1+d\sqrt[3]{2}+e\sqrt[3]{4}$, because $2c$ is always even.

**Edit in response to changes by OP to the original question**: What if we further assume that $\alpha$ is prime to the discriminant of the field? The answer is still no, in general.

Let once again $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$. This time, choose as a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis elements $\{1,w_2,w_3\}$ where
$$w_2=3+\sqrt[3]{2},\ w_3=w_2^2 = (3+\sqrt[3]{2})^2.$$
It is easy to see that $\{1,w_2,w_3\}$ forms a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ because $\sqrt[3]{2}=w_2-3$ and $\sqrt[3]{4}=w_3-6w_2+9$. Now let $\alpha=w_2=3+\sqrt[3]{2}$. The norm of $\alpha$ is $29$, so $\alpha$ is "primitive" and prime to the discriminant of the field $D_K=2^23^3$. Let $\beta=a+bw_2+cw_2^2$ be an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$. Then:
$$\alpha\cdot \beta = w_2(a+bw_2+cw_2^2)=aw_2+bw_2^2+cw_2^3.$$
Since
$$w_2^3=(3+\sqrt[3]{2})^3 = 29-27w_2+9w_2^3$$
we obtain
$$\alpha\cdot \beta = w_2(a+bw_2+cw_2^2)=aw_2+bw_2^2+cw_2^3=29c+(a-27c)w_2+(b+9c)w_2^2.$$
Hence, $\alpha\cdot \beta$ can't be of the form $1+dw_2+ew_2^3$ because $29c$ is always a multiple of $29$.

Comment: Thank you! What if I assume that $\alpha$ is prime to the discriminant of $K$ ?

Comment: Sorry I un-accepted your excellent answer! I am requesting more information now so it seems appropriate to un-accept.

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I'm satisfied now!

Comment: @SamuelHambleton : How are you sir, you have answered my previous questions sir, and encouraged me, but after that you never turned to me. Anyway thank you sir for what you did.

Comment: Hello Iyengar. I read all of your questions. There are people here who know much more than I about most of those topics.